# How to get nth jQuery element

Tags: jquery

In jQuery, `$("...").get(3)` returns the 3rd DOM element. What is the function to return the 3rd jQuery element?

Answer (score 336, accepted):

Why not browse the (short) selectors page first?

Here it is: the [`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) operator. It is used just like `get()`, but it returns the jQuery object.

Or you can use `.eq()` function too.

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be `.eq()` instead of `:eq()`?

Comment: Yes, `.eq()` is more appropriate for the OP's question. `:eq()` is used within the string parameter to `$`, whereas `.eq()` is a method on an existing jQuery object.

Comment: I swear I have to go and look this up *every*. *single*. *time*.

Comment: What about if the returned elements aren't siblings? Like getting an option in an opt group? `$('select').find('option').eq(n)`, doesn't work if options are nested in various opt groups.

Comment: @JoelWorsham Depends on the desired behavior. `$('select').find('option').eq(n)` will basically ignore the grouping, and get all options as a whole. If you want it per group, something like this is necessary: `$('select').find('optgroup').each(function() { $(this).find('option').eq(n)...; })`

Comment: Amazing how many people upvoted something that actually has the answer in the comments. here is a link to `.eq()` - https://api.jquery.com/eq/ since the answer link takes you to `:eq()`

Comment: "Why not browse the (short) selectors page first?" - Because "eq" is a very bad name and I regularly just skip over it as eq for me means comparison....

Comment: Yes, it would better be named `at()` or `atIndex()` to be discoverable. But the jQuery API design is of low quality in general.

Comment: Remember that eq is zero based, so the first element is :eq(0), and the fifth element is .eq(4)

Comment: @Dykam if your were to move your comment of  _Jan 30 '15 at 9:04_ into the actual answer, and add a couple of examples showing html and resulting selection, it would be _so_ much more helpful.

Comment: [As of jQuery 3.4, the :eq pseudo-class is deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/). Remove it from your selectors and filter the results later using .eq().

Answer (score 376):

You can use the [:eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector, for example:

```
$("td:eq(2)").css("color", "red"); // gets the third td element
```

Or the [eq(int)](https://api.jquery.com/eq/#eq-index) function:

```
$("td").eq(2).css("color", "red");
```

Also, remember that the indexes are zero-based.

Comment: As a synonym, you can also use the [`:nth()`](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation#wiki-selectors) selector -- not to be confused with `:nth-child()`

Comment: The better answer and not edited 3 years after the fact :)

Comment: thank you for actually explaining how to use the selector/function

Answer (score 53):

if you have control over the query which builds the jQuery object, use `:eq()`

```
$("div:eq(2)")
```

If you don't have control over it (for example, it's being passed from another function or something), then use `.eq()`

```
var $thirdElement = $jqObj.eq(2);
```

Or if you want a section of them (say, the third, fourth and fifth elements), use `.slice()`

```
var $third4th5thElements = $jqObj.slice(2, 5);
```

Comment: Was looking for slice, but wasn't sure how to search. Thanks for going beyond what is required in the original question.

Comment: For people who stumble on this answer, a helpful point to note is that the nth-child selector is 1 based while :eq or .eq() are 0 based

Comment: You should use `.eq()` instead of `:eq()` actually. Slight performance boost.

Answer (score 14):

I think you can use this

```
$("ul li:nth-child(2)").append("<span> - 2nd!</span>");
```

It finds the second li in each matched ul and notes it.

Answer (score 11):

.eq() -An integer indicating the 0-based position of the element.

Ex:

Consider a page with a simple list on it:

```
<ul>
<li>list item 1</li>
<li>list item 2</li>
<li>list item 3</li>
<li>list item 4</li>
</ul>
```

We can apply this method to the set of list items:

```
$( "li" ).eq( 2 ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

[For more information :  .eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Answer (score 4):

If you already have the jquery object in a variable, you can also just treat it as a normal indexed array, without the use of jquery:

```
var all_rows = $("tr");
for(var i=0; i < all_rows.length; i++){
   var row = all_rows[i];
   //additionally, you can use it again in a jquery selector
   $(row).css("background-color","black");
}
```

Although the above example is not useful in any way, it is representing how you can treat objects created by jquery as indexed arrays.

Comment: Right, and one more (hopefully useful) hint: If row contains a list of `<select>` elements, and you want the selected combobox element, use **`$(row).val();`**

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you can always just wrap the get function like so:

```
var $someJqueryEl = $($('.myJqueryEls').get(3));
```

Comment: This is just the "hard way" and this is what `eq()` gives you for free.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fetch particular element/node or tag in loop for e.g.

```
<p class="weekday" data-today="monday">Monday</p>
<p class="weekday" data-today="tuesday">Tuesday</p>
<p class="weekday" data-today="wednesday">Wednesday</p>
<p class="weekday" data-today="thursday">Thursday</p>
```

So, from above code loop is executed and we want particular field to select for that we have to use jQuery selection that can select only expecting element from above loop so, code will be

```
$('.weekdays:eq(n)');
```

e.g.

```
$('.weekdays:eq(0)');
```

as well as by other method

```
$('.weekday').find('p').first('.weekdays').next()/last()/prev();
```

but first method is more efficient when `HTML <tag>` has unique class name.

NOTE:Second method is use when their is no class name in target element or node.

for more follow https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 0):

For iterations using a selector doesn't seem to make any sense though:

```
var some = $( '...' );

for( i = some.length -1; i>=0; --i )
{
   // Have to transform in a jquery object again:
   //
   var item = $( some[ i ] );

   // use item at will
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Live Example to access and remove the Nth element with jQuery:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('li:eq(1)').hide();
      });
    </script>
    <ol>
      <li>First</li>
      <li>Second</li>
      <li>Third</li>
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

When it runs, there are two items in the ordered list that show, First, and Third.  The second was hidden.

Comment: P.S. : The count start from 0; First is at index 0, Second is at index 1 and so on ....

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function(){
            $(document).find('div').siblings().each(function(){
                var obj = $(this);
                obj.find('div').each(function(){
                    var obj1 = $(this);
                    if(!obj1.children().length > 0){
                        alert(obj1.html());
                    }
                });

            });
        });

<div id="2">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>XYZ Pvt. Ltd.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="3">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>ABC Pvt Ltd.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "$(function(){" first of fall, i have created anonymous function, which fired automatically. Inside that, i found three parent div using siblings. Then i iterated in all 3 parent div and check the length of every children length. How i can identify that whether is a last div or not in parent div. Now i am alerting the last div html of every 3 main parent div.

Comment: You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35128846/edit) your answer, instead of giving information in comments :)