# Apply function to only one div class, not all

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm currently working on a location page on a website and am having trouble with a show/hide jquery effect. The jQuery below activates on-click and applies toggles the class of a div to show/hide it... pretty straightforward. However, when I add more divs with the same class and click on the activator link, it runs the functions on all of the divs. I know this is a simple fix, but I can't figure out the right syntax. Could anyone take a quick look at this code and see about how I could fix it. I only included one of the html divs below. It's when I have more than one that causes the problem. See [example here](http://rgw.steadfastdesignfirm.com).

Thanks,
Taylor

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $(".sliding").hide();
    $(".show-hide").show();
    $(".hide-click").show();

    $('.show-hide').click(function(){   
        $(".sliding").slideToggle("slow");
        $(".hide-click").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- Bowie, MD -->
<div class="location" style="margin-top: 0;">

<!-- City Name -->
<h3><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="show-hide">Bowie</a></h3>

    <h2>Address</h2>
    <p>16901 Melford Blvd, Suite 11<br/>
    Bowie, MD 20715</p>

    <h2>Contact</h2>
    <p><span><strong>Phone:</strong> 301.805.5395</span><br />
    <span><strong>Fax:</strong> 301.805.5396</span></p>

    <span class="hide-click"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="show-hide">View additional info</a></span>

    <!-- Hidden Content -->
    <div class="sliding">

        <h2>Map</h2>

        <div class="map">   
            <iframe width="211" height="140" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=16901+Melford+Blvd,+Suite+11+Bowie,+MD+20715&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=61.023673,112.236328&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=16901+Melford+Blvd,+Bowie,+Maryland+20715&amp;ll=38.959742,-76.714354&amp;spn=0.009344,0.018196&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
        </div>

        <a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=16901+Melford+Blvd,+Suite+11+Bowie,+MD+20715&daddr=&hl=en&geocode=&mra=prev&sll=38.959741,-76.714349&sspn=0.00755,0.013422&g=16901+Melford+Blvd,+Suite+11+Bowie,+MD+20715&ie=UTF8&z=17" target="_blank" class="directions">Get Directions</a>

        <h2>Doctors</h2>
        <p><a href="/#phillips.php">William B. Phillips, II M.D.</a>, <a href="/#weichel.php">Eric D. Weichel, M.D.</a></p>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="show-hide">Hide additional info</a>

    </div>
    <!-- end Hidden Content -->

</div>
<!-- end Location -->
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I definitely had the right logic going in my head and I was trying .parent() and other delegation selectors, but @joekarl really nailed it by going and finding parent elements and then working back down the list from there to make it specific to the current div. Just what I needed. Thank you all, again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're wanting just the .sliding content that's associated with its .show-hide link to toggle. You can set the jQuery context to find the correct .sliding element. This way you don't assume that the element is at a certain position and you're not tied to unique css ids allowing more flexibility.

```
$(function(){
    $(".sliding").hide();
    $(".show-hide").show();
    $(".hide-click").show();

    $('.show-hide').click(function(){   
        //find the surrounding div
        var location = $(this).parent().parent();

        //find the correct elements within the location block
        $(".sliding",location).slideToggle("slow");
        $(".hide-click",location).slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `:first` or `:nth-child` selectors.

See the JQuery documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Example:

```js
$(".sliding").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give your `div` an `id`, and then use `#divID` in your jQuery selector to only select that one `div`:

`$('#divID').hide();`

The whole point of an ID is that it can only be applied to one element in the page, whereas classes can be applied to any number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Two options are:

1) to use an id selector as the argument to $() and add an id attribute to only the one div you want,

`<div id="someid">`  and then js looks like this `$("#someid").show()`

2) Use $( $().get(N) ).show() where N is the known index of the div you want to affect.  Hard to recommend this solution, though, as it has a greater chance of breaking down if you re-format the page.

Answer (score 1):

for the div you can use

```
  $(this).parents(".sliding").slideToggle("slow")
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this.

Firstly set up all your divs other than the first one with the class `dn` set to `display:none` in your css.

Then your javascript you could do something like this.
I'm assuming you want your click triggers to be visible always.

```
$(function(){

    $('.show-hide').click(function(){

        $(".sliding").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).next(".sliding).slideDown("slow");

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
$(".sliding:eq(0)").slideToggle("slow");
```

will set it to the first element of class ".sliding".

See:   [How to get nth jQuery element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442925/how-to-get-nth-jquery-element)

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for the answers. This doesn't work because I don't want it to only activate the first item on the page. I want the same script to apply to other divs on the page as they're clicked on. Please view the example here: http://rgw.steadfastdesignfirm.com/#locations.php