# State dependent class names on accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, accordion

So I have this problem that I guess is a walk in the park to fix.

I'm using the JS snippet below on a website I'm building and what the snippet does is it creates accordions for some HTML elements where the class `.bapf_head` is the header (control) of the accordion and the `.bapf_body` is the expand/collapse.

I wrote the `if` logic where the function checks if the `.bapf_body` is opened or not and will then add or remove a class to the `.bapf_head` depending on the state. This then results in a +/- symbol that indicates open/close depending on the state.

So the problem is that I have multiple Div's that uses the same class names and all of them gets updated with the `.open` class name when one of the accordions are opened or closed. So let's say I have three accordions and I open one of them, then all three gets the class `.open` added and hence all gets the '-' symbol even though only one accordion is open.

Anyone knows how to make sure only the clicked accordion gets the updated class-name rather then all of the accordions at the same time?

Code below;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".bapf_head").click(function () {
        $header = $(this);
        $content = $header.next();
        $content.slideToggle(300, function () {
            $header.text(function () {
                if ($content.is(":visible")) {
                    $(".bapf_head").addClass("open");
                } else {
                    $(".bapf_head").removeClass("open");
                };          
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply function to only one div class, not all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347016/apply-function-to-only-one-div-class-not-all)

Comment: The logic inside  `text(function)` has nothing to do with text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     if ($content.is(":visible")) {
         $(this).addClass("open");
     } else {
         $(this).removeClass("open");
     };
```

you need to reference the event-related DOM element, not select all the ones with that class

also, `.click()` is long deprecated afaik, you should use `.on('click', ...`

Comment: You my friend might not wear a cape - nonetheless you're a god damn hero!