# How do I select the nth child using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get nth jQuery element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442925/how-to-get-nth-jquery-element)

I have this simple code:

```
<ul>
 <li>one</li>
 <li>two</li>
 <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

I know that my 2nd element should have a class active, how do I add this class?

this code won't work:

```
$('ul li').get(1).addClass('active')
```

I assume it is becuase it returns a dom element and not jquery element. but how do I do it right?

=======

Of course 2nd element is an example. I need each time to change the active class from a variable called theActiveClassNumber

Comment: haven't found it - thanks for letting me know..

Comment: You're right, that's a DOM element, so, strangely enough, this will work, although I don't recommed it: `$($('ul li').get(1)).addClass('active')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("ul li:nth-child(2)").addClass('active')
```

or

```
$("ul li:eq(1)").addClass('active')
```

Answer (score 0):

`get()` returns a DOM element so you have to re-wrap in the jQuery object:

```
$( $('ul li').get(1) ).addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like @Kanishka answer that work to, but you can try this one too, may be can help you,

```
$("ul li:nth-child(even)").addClass('active');
$("ul li:nth-child(odd)").addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to the question, but:
If you want to get certain jQuery Object, you should use .eq() instead of .get().