# How do I obtain a particular element using its tag name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using `$('div').css('color', 'red');` but I want the 5th div in my code to have red text. How would I do this?

Comment: have you tried using .each()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('div:eq(4)').css('color', 'red')
```

the :eq selector takes a 0-based integer

http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: I always use the function thinking that is better for performance but I haven't tested it `$('div').eq(4).css('color', 'red')` Imma run a jsPerf and see...

Comment: Indeed, the `:eq` selector is way slower than the `eq()` function. [jsPerf Test](http://jsperf.com/eq-selector-vs-eq-function-in-jquery)

Comment: For speed, `getElementsByTagName` runs rings around any jQuery equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the title question, if the particular element is named foo, you would use `$('#foo')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [:eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) jQuery selector. See jsFiddle here:

- http://jsfiddle.net/VzKkc/

Also see this SOq:

- [How to get nth jQuery element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442925/how-to-get-nth-jquery-element)

Answer (score 0):

POJS:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[5].style.color = 'red';
```

It might be boring, but it's 20 to [30 times faster](http://jsperf.com/eq-selector-vs-eq-function-in-jquery/2) than the jQuery equivalent in IE 8.