# jQuery access each matched element from '.find' by an index

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery's `.find()` method to return a set of elements, I am trying to access items in the returned set by their order in that set.

For example, a table with two rows and in each row a select box and two text input fields, accessed with the following:

```
$('table#tbl').find('tr.row').each(function(i)
{

});
```

To get the first element I would have thought I could use

```
$('table#tbl').find('tr.row').each(function(i)
{
    alert( $(this).find(':input').get(1).val() );
});
```

And variations of the above, but apparently this doesn't work. Could anyone suggest the correct method to access item x of n elements returned?

Edit:

JSFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lenqt/42/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get nth jQuery element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442925/how-to-get-nth-jquery-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alert( $(this).find(':input:eq(0)').val() );
```