# focus over first classname element

Tags: jquery

I have a validation form.
When php found errors, sends inputs with "error" class... for example:

```
<input type='text' name='login' class='error'/>
<input type='password' name='pass'/>
<input type='text' name='email' class='error'/>
```

My question is, how i can set focus over first "error" class element with jquery? if i try this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    if($(".error").length != 0){$(".error").focus();}
</script>
```

Always sets focus over last element.
Thanks for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get nth jQuery element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442925/how-to-get-nth-jquery-element)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `:first` selector.

```
$("input.error:first").focus()
```

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways to do it.

```
$('.error:first').focus()

$('.error').first().focus()

$('.error').eq(0).focus()
```

you may refer to the documents:

- http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/first/
- http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Comment: nice, i will read it, thanks for multiple solutions. Up to you too