# Get a specific element from elements with same class

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have a html code like this:

```
<div class="color">
    <span>red</span
</div>
<div class="color">
    <span>green</span
</div>
<div class="color">
    <span>blue</span
</div>
```

What I want is to get the second div with the class "color". I know I could loop through them with each() and get it from the loop, but I'm pretty sure there's an easier way to do this.

```
var id = 1

function GetColor(id) {
    //get the second div with the class "color"
}
```

How could this be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get nth jQuery element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442925/how-to-get-nth-jquery-element)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/get/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said jQuery, here you go,

```
$('div.color').eq(1); // will get the second one.
```