# Getting textbox value inside gridview using JQuery, val() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have `TextBox` inside `GridView`'s `ItemTemplate`. I assigned it `CssClass` to `grdtxtbox` and trying to get their values using `.val()`

My `aspx` code is as below

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No. Of Days">

    <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtDays" runat="server" CssClass="grdtxtbox"></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and `JQuery` as below

```
var  leaveTextBoxes = $(".grdtxtbox");
            for (var i = 0; i < leaveTextBoxes.length; i++) {
                alert(leaveTextBoxes[i].val());
            }
```

I can  `alert(leaveTextBoxes[i].length)` length properly, means code looks fine but `.val()` is not working. Error on this line is `Undefined is not a function` nor I am getting `.val()` in intellisense.

**Update**
However `.value` is working fine there. What the problem with `.val()`?

Comment: try `$(leaveTextBoxes[i]).val()`

Comment: This should have been the answer @Bharadwaj

Comment: is that solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

try using this but I'm not sure:

```
$("#Gridid .grdtxtbox").each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: where 'Gridid ' is the id value of your gridview

Answer (score 0):

Use the [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) selector to select the nth element, as shown in this answer: [How to get nth jQuery element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442925/how-to-get-nth-jquery-element)

```
for(i=0; i<leaveTextBoxes.length; i++){
    alert(leaveTextBoxes.eq(i).val());
}
```

Alternatively,

```
for(i=0; i<leaveTextBoxes.length; i++){
    alert(leaveTextBoxes.get(i).value); //plain-old-js
    alert($(leaveTextBoxes.get(i)).val()); //dirty but works
}
```