# JQuery: Set attribute for nth element by name selector

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Having a set of "**a**" tag with the same name:

```
<a name="link" href="http://link1">
<a name="link" href="http://link2">
<a name="link" href="http://link3">
```

I need to **change** the **href attribute** for the third element with `$("['name=link']")` selector, but is not working with **prop**/**attr** method.

Comment: create jsfiddle for it if possible...

Comment: try this.. $("[name='link']")

Comment: The name attribute on anchors is obsolete.

Comment: try this $("[name='link']:eq(2)")

Comment: You mean `$('a[name="link"]:nth-child(3)')` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get nth jQuery element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442925/how-to-get-nth-jquery-element)

Comment: in html5, the name attribute on an anchor is now obsolete and shouldn't be used.  Why not use a class?

Comment: I not really understand why it should be a duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm trying to understand your question.

By your explanation, I suggest you to try to use ":eq" jQuery Selector. The code'll be something like this:

```
// eq takes element by index (from 0 to *) in the same 'root' of nodes in DOM structure
$("a[name='link']:eq(2)").attr('href', '__new value__');
```

Here's the official jQuery documentation to this feature: https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a[name='link']:eq(2)").attr('href', '__new value__');

  // checking the href value in the console
  console.log($("a[name='link']:eq(2)").attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a name="link" href="http://link1">1st link</a>
<a name="link" href="http://link2">2nd link</a>
<a name="link" href="http://link3">3rd link</a>
```