# How can i select and display text from the third div with jquery

Tags: jquery

lets say theres 4 divs

```
<div class="list">
  <div class="hello">hello</div>
  <div class="hello">how</div>
  <div class="hello">are</div>
  <div class="hello">you</div>
</div>
```

how can i select the third one and display the text with jquery?

```
$('.hello')[2].text()
```

trying to use something like that.

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442925/how-to-get-nth-jquery-element

Comment: Try $('.hello:eq(2)').text().  See https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/ for details.

Answer (score 0):

Add id to div and use it in that way:

```
$('#myid').text()
```